# How do I keep the center of the radar chart

Tags: excel, charts

I have a list of values that are plotted onto the radar chart/spider diagram in Excel.  How do I keep the center of the radar chart to remain a value of "0"? It changes when certain values are plotted onto the chart.

Comment: You need to change the axes minimum scale to 0 (ex. `ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to format the boundaries for your values in the graph. Right click on your numbers in the graph (in my case 0, 20, 40 ,60 ,80) and choose "Format Axis". Then set the Bounds to 0,0.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this seemed to have worked.  Do you by chance know how to lets say if I have an output of "N/A" to make this equivalent to "100%" on radar chart?  Right now is equivalent to a score of "0".

Comment: Unfortunately not. Excel treats N/A as 0 per default in most chart types. I see two solutions:
1. Make all the "N/A" values to "100%" values.
2. Remove all "N/A". 
Then you right click on your chart -> Select Data. 
Choose "Hidden and Empty Cells". 
Here you can choose how you want to treat empty cells. Either as "0", as Gap in your chart or your could ignore those row values....